# Including css to React failed to compile

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to create a TopNav.js component.

My app.js includes this TopNav

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

import TopNav from './components/Menu/TopNav';

function App() {
  return (
    <TopNav />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my TopNav.js:

```
import React from 'react';

import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';

const topNav = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <header class="header_main">
            <section class="container">
                <section class="row">
                    <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <figure class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png"  alt=""/></a></figure>
                    </section>
                    <section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <ul class="nav_main pull-right">
                            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </header>
    </Aux>
);

export default topNav;
```

The Aux.js is just to wrap something.

```
const aux = (props) => props.children;

export default aux;
```

I include the css files in my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import './css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './css/main.css';
import './css/media.css';

import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

When I try to compile this project, it returns:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/css/font-awesome.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/css/font-awesome.min.css)
```

Can't I use CSS in React projects?

Thanks

Comment: Can you put your file named `font-awesome.min.css` it is the problem, of course that you can use CSS in react projects =)

Comment: Are you using CRA? If not, you'll have to specify a css loader in your webpack config to handle .css file compilation.

Comment: @MarcoMesen ```font-awesone.min.css``` is already the file name. What do you mean?

Comment: @LenJoseph What is a CRA? I'm just using Rect

Comment: Sorry Im wront the others comments could be correct, if you dont use CRA Create-React-App you need to configurate the webpack to handle .css files.

Comment: I did use the create react app. ```npx create-react-app my-app```